# feedback and corrected answers on my solution in calculus 1

Tags: calculus

Find the derivatives of $f(x)=|x|$ using the first principle.

answer:

$|x|=\sqrt{x^{2}}$

$f(x+h)=\sqrt{(x+h)^2}$

now use

$$
\begin{align}
f'(x) & =\lim_{h\rightarrow0}
  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\[12pt]
& =\frac{1}{h}(\sqrt{(x+h)^2}-\sqrt{x^2}) \\[12pt]
& =\frac{1}{h}((x+h)-x) \\[12pt]
& =\frac{h}{h} \\[12pt]
f'(x) & =1
\end{align}
$$

please tell me if whatever i have done is correct. please help as i am still a student studying calculus 1.

Comment: You miss the possible negative case when you resolve the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ |x| = \left \{ \begin{array}{cc} x & x>0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \\ -x & x< 0 \end{array} \right. $$

This of course means

$$\frac{d}{dx} |x| = \left \{ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & x>0 \\ -1 & x< 0 \end{array} \right. $$

The derivative at $0$ is easily seen to not be defined (since it's a sharp edge!)

Edit: take the limit from the negative side you'll get $-1$, take it from the positive side you get $1$, since the limits aren't the same. The limit does not exist.

Comment: so how do i use the first principle to show that

Comment: @john: By plugging the above definition of $|x|$ into the limit! It may help to break the problem into cases depending on the value of $x$.... It's important to note that if $x \neq 0$, then you can pick a $\delta$ such that for all $h$ satisfying $|h| < \delta$, $x+h$ has the same sign as $x$.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct when $x$ is positive.  When $x$ is negative, then $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ (which is positive) and $\sqrt{(x+h)^2}=-(x+h)$ for sufficiently small values of $h$ (and "sufficiently small" values are the only ones that matter when we're talking about a limit as $h\to0$).

So you get $1$ if $x>0$ and $-1$ if $x<0$, and a more complicated situation if $x=0$.